# How to compare 2 predictive models where one uses predictor with missing values

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, model-selection, missing-data

I am developing a model to predict `y` from a dataset (N=20,000) that contains `x1`, `x2`. 
Say I want to compare the models `lm(y~x1+x2,data)` with `lm(y~x1,data)`.
Predictive accuracy is my goal so I decided to put them through a k-fold cross validation and measure the mean squared prediction error.

The problem is that `x2` is only available on 20% of the entire dataset. So how would you fairly compare these models?

Would you just focus on the 20% of data? This seems wasteful to me.

Answer (score 1):

You will ultimately be limited by the 20% nonmissing data.

MAB's solution will not offer a valid comparison, as you cannot calculate the model containing x2 for 80% of subjects- regardless of validation or derivation sets.

Answer (score 0):

More experienced users might correct me on this - but throwing out cases (as some have mentioned) will produce unbiased estimates only if the data are *missing completely at random* (MCAR). I don't know if that's a reasonable assumption with your data. 
There are methods to impute or "fill in" missing data. Gelman and Hill (2006) pp. 529-545 has a good introduction to missing data with examples describing imputation methods.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of fair comparison is in focusing on the question: Why you want to compare the two models ? The reason will justify how we can do a fair comparison.

Compare on just 20% if :

The purpose of comparison is to figure out which model is better when both x1 and x2 are available (ofcourse the assumption is that 20% is representative of the test data having both x1 and x2)

Compare on all 100% :

if : you want to quantify the real-world-returns each model will give you on complete data which is expected to have data with x2 missing

by : defining the value of output as $n.d.$ for 80% cases (where you have no x2 available) and modifying the error function by assigning a value to ${y_{true} - n.d. }$ as some real-number/function which shows the impact a $n.d.$ will have on the real world application.

example : in case $y$ represents the stock market index and a $n.d.$ will mean you won't know the stock market movement for the next day and hence not invest money into it; incurring no loss and no profit you might want to assign a value $0$ to ${y_{true} - n.d. }$ as it doesn't affect you much. On the other hand if you are a stock trader by profession, not knowing a prediction might just be unacceptable to you in which case you can assign a VERY large value even +infinity to ${y_{true} - n.d. }$

---

$n.d.$ stands for not defined.